# Deserialize Complex xml to Object C#

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, soap

I am trying to deserialize the following XML response from a webservice to C# objects. But somehow the elements return null. I have looked at a number of examples online, i'm not sure where i am getting it wrong.

```
 <SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">
   <SOAP-ENV:Header/>
      <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <ns4:postTransactionResponse xmlns:ns3=\"http://www.domain/cash/api\" xmlns:ns4=\"http://www.domain/cash/api/soap\">
          <ns3:return>
            <field1>200</field1>
            <field2>FIRSTNAME SURNAME</field2>
            <field5>SUBSCRIBER</field5>
            <field6>FIRSTNAME SURNAME</field6>
            <field7>Active</field7>
            <field8>USD</field8>
         </ns3:return>
      </ns4:postTransactionResponse>
   </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

I am using the following classes

```
   [XmlRoot("Envelope", Namespace = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/")]
public class Envelope
{
    [DataMember(Name = "Header", Order = 0)]
    public object Header;

    [DataMember(Name = "Body", Order = 1)]
    public EnvelopeBody Body;
}

[XmlRoot("Body", Namespace = "http://www.domain/cash/api/soap")]
public class EnvelopeBody
{
    [DataMember(Name = "postTransactionResponse", Order = 0)]
    public PostTransactionResponse postTransactionResponse;
}

[XmlRoot("postTransactionResponse", Namespace = "http://www.domain/cash/api/soap")]
public class PostTransactionResponse
{
    [DataMember(Name = "return", Order = 0)]
    public ResponseModel return_;
}

[XmlRoot("return", Namespace = "http://www.domain/cash/api")]
public class ResponseModel
{
    [XmlElement("field1")]
    public string field1;

    [XmlElement("field2")]
    public string field2;

    [XmlElement("field3")]
    public string field3 ;

    [XmlElement("field4")]
    public string field4 ;

    [XmlElement("field5")]
    public string field5 ;

    [XmlElement("field6")]
    public string field6 ;

    [XmlElement("field7")]
    public string field7 ;

    [XmlElement("field8")]
    public string field8 ;

    [XmlElement("field9")]
    public string field9 ;

    [XmlElement("field10")]
    public string field10 ;

    [XmlElement("field11")]
    public string field11 ;

    [XmlElement("field12")]
    public string field12 ;

    [XmlElement("field13")]
    public string field13 ;

    [XmlElement("field14")]
    public string field14 ;

    [XmlElement("field15")]
    public string field15 ;
}
```

Here is my code that i am using to deserialize the XML Response. I am using Stream Reader and The Envelope class to get the fields.

```
            //Getting response from request  
        using (WebResponse Serviceres = request.GetResponse())
        {
            using (StreamReader rd = new StreamReader(Serviceres.GetResponseStream()))
            {

                XmlSerializer sr = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Envelope));
                var obj = (Envelope)sr.Deserialize(rd);
                var dat = obj.Body;
                var un = dat.postTransactionResponse;
                var u = un.return_;  //This is giving null
                var p = u.field2;    //This is giving null
            }
    }
```

The ResponseModel is giving all nulls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your provided xml, I generated (by the use of xsd.exe) xsd files (3 created:

```
e:\>xsd env.xml /c /out:temp\
Microsoft (R) Xml Schemas/DataTypes support utility
[Microsoft (R) .NET Framework, Version 4.6.1586.0]
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
Writing file 'temp\env.xsd'.
```

Afterwards I created, based on the xsd, the classes:

```
E:\temp>xsd.exe /c /namespace:SampleNs /language:CS env.xsd env_app1.xsd env_app2.xsd
Microsoft (R) Xml Schemas/DataTypes support utility
[Microsoft (R) .NET Framework, Version 4.6.1586.0]
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
Writing file 'E:\temp\env_env_app1_env_app2.cs'.
```

Adding the resulting file to the project and everything is running...
For information what was wrong with your definition - you can compare the generated classes with your (Eg. your body should be an array or List).

For external xml / more complex xml I would suggest to always take use of xsd.exe (making your life a lot easier).

[image]